# DRF - how to concatenate two different models in one .json api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have task to output to different models in one .json file

So I need at the end two different models look like this on one api page:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cat_dog_api/

My goal output:

```
[
    {
        "dog_big": "Mastiff",
        "dog_small": "Terrier",
        "same_line": "different words 1",

    },
    {
        "cat_big": "Singapura",
        "cat_small": "Maine Coon",
        "same_line": "different words 2",
    }
]
```

Example models:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    cat_big = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    cat_small = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    same_line = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class Dog(models.Model):
    dog_big = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    dog_small = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    same_line = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

I found out how to concatenate models with "chain" in one queryset

Views.py:

```
from itertools import chain

class Whole_test(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Cat_dog_Serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return list(chain(Cat.objects.all(), Dog.objects.all()))
```

But I'm stuck when time comes to serializer,
I have to choose one model with serialiser,

```
class Cat_dog_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        fields = '__all__'
```

but in this case it doesn't serealize my Dog model from my queryset

Is there a way to achieve my goal, maybe a different approach from mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
pip install django-rest-multiple-models
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'drf_multiple_model',
)
```

Views.py

`from drf_multiple_model.views import FlatMultipleModelAPIView`

```
class Dog_cat_view_api(FlatMultipleModelAPIView):
    pagination_class = None
    add_model_type = False
    querylist = [
        {'queryset': Dog.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': Dof_Serializer},
        {'queryset': Cat.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': Cat_Serializer},
    ]
```

here is anothere view in which i can retrive data from GET/POST/DELETE/PUT requests, which you can use for filtering

```
class Dog_cat_view_api(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    def get_querylist(self):

        #this is a user(header Authorization:token 123123)
        user = self.request.user 
        #this is data (in body(form-data))
        data = self.request.data

        querylist = [
            {'queryset': Dog.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': Dof_Serializer},
            {'queryset': Cat.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': Cat_Serializer},
        ]
        return querylist
```

Serializer.py

```
class Dog_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = '__all__'

class Cat_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
path('cat_dog_api/', views.Dog_cat_view_api.as_view(), name="cat_dog_api"),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need nested serializers inside Cat_dog_Serializer.

```
class CatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        fields = '__all__'

class DogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = '__all__'

class Cat_dog_Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    cat = CatSerializer()
    dog = DogSerializer()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["cat", "dog",]
```

You can read more here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: This is not working, this is only for nested models, but models in the task aren't nested. They are independent

Comment: This should definitely work. Why it doesn't work? Do you get some errors?

Comment: your code is legit, only Cat_dog_Serializer fields are incoret should work <<fields = "_all_">>. Your code will serialize only 1 model on 1st level, and 2 models on 2nd level, this is code for nested models. But my models in the tasks aren't nested, they are independant, "parallel"